# Optimizing code resampling with large size tick data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have a dataframe(df, number of rows: 79446767) like this:

```
                            Price  Volume
date                                     
2016-05-01 22:00:00.334338  45.90    20.0
2016-05-01 22:00:00.335312    NaN     1.0
2016-05-01 22:00:00.538377  45.92     1.0
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590386  45.92     1.0    
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493  45.92     1.0
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493  45.92     1.0
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493  45.92     1.0
(..omitted rows)
```

I resampled by time(for this: 1 hour) with this dataframe, like:

```
                     Price                         Volume    
                     close   open    high   low      sum
date                                                     
2016-05-01 22:00:00  45.57  45.90  45.96  45.55    4842.0
2016-05-01 23:00:00  45.66  45.59  45.68  45.56    2009.0
2016-05-02 00:00:00  45.64  45.66  45.68  45.58    1869.0
2016-05-02 01:00:00  45.61  45.64  45.68  45.59    1312.0
2016-05-02 02:00:00  45.58  45.62  45.65  45.55    1504.0
2016-05-02 03:00:00  45.47  45.58  45.61  45.47    1347.0
2016-05-02 04:00:00  45.47  45.48  45.55  45.43    2965.0
(..omitted rows)
```

But it takes about 15 minutes to execute. Is there another way to resample with fast speed? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

aggregator = {
            "Price": ["last", "first", np.max, np.min],
            "Volume": "sum"
        }    
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=1H, label='right')).agg(aggregator).dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

Comment: Out of interest, how much faster was the `resample` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `resample` method with the `H` argument to group by hour. It is more efficient than using `groupby` for large sets of time series data.

Aggregating with the `'ohlc'` argument will then give you the buckets you want for price, while the `'sum'` argument will give you the total volume.

```
df.resample('H').agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```